# Bash - how to use the for loop to run commands sequentially

Tags: bash

A toy example:

I want to run the following commands sequentially

```
python generate.py 1
python simulate.py 1
python generate.py 2
python simulate.py 2
...
python generate.py 100
python simulate.py 100
```

Given the large number of commands, I'd like to use a for loop along the lines

```
for i in {1..100}; do \
    python generate.py $i; python simulate.py $i; \
done
```

It's very important for the jobs to run one after the next. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I wonder if the use of backslashes is necessary?

Comment: You don't need the backslashes, although using them is fine (except that it will look like you are joining them in one long line to the lexer).

Comment: Better to join the commands with `&&` to prevent the second running if the first fails.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you are doing this correctly. The loop you've written will execute the commands in the exact order you listed them out long-hand, though it is important to note that an error in one command will not cause the loop to terminate, it will continue with the next command, effectively ignoring the error.

Comment: Thanks, John! If I may, I have another question. Previously, I had
`for i in {1..100};`  
`do`  
    `python generate.py $i`  
    `python simulate.py $i`  
`done`  

but it didn't work, difference being in the semi-colons. Sorry, I'm new to this so I couldn't create new lines correctly in the comment. Can you explain why?

Comment: The problem was that you needed a "command seeparator" between the `generate.py` and the `simulate.py` scripts. Either a newline or a semicolon would have worked; you didn't need the semicolon at the end of that line (though having it didn't hurt anything).

Comment: or, as  User112638726 suggested above use `&&` instead of `;` so that `simulate.py` only runs if `generate.py` finishes without error.  e.g. `for i in {1..100}; do python generate.py $i && python simulate.py $i ; done`

Comment: you can also use `set -e` before the `for` loop and `set +e` after it to cause the entire loop to exit if any error occurs in any of the generate.py or simulate.py instances.  this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @cas and @User112638726. If I wanted each command to only run if every command finished without error, would it be `for i in {1..100}; do python generate.py $i && python simulate.py $i && done`?

Comment: no, use the `set -e` command i mentioned earlier.  that tells bash to exit on any error.  use `set +e` afterwards to cancel that behaviour (otherwise your shell will die the first time anything exits with a non-zero exit code).

Comment: s/tells bash to exit/tells bash to exit *the loop*/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are. A simple way to check would be to echo the commands instead of running them:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do 
     echo python generate.py "$i"
     echo python simulate.py "$i" 
 done
python generate.py 1
python simulate.py 1
python generate.py 2
python simulate.py 2
python generate.py 3
python simulate.py 3
python generate.py 4
python simulate.py 4
python generate.py 5
python simulate.py 5
```

As you can see in the above example, the commands are launched as you want them.